# How old is the word "prolly"?

Tags: etymology, slang

*Prolly* is given this definition at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prolly):

> Clipped pronunciation of probably.

I was reading an interesting article today that [claimed *prolly* dates](http://www.good.is/post/let-s-bury-the-not-a-word-myth/) from 1947 and that surprised me. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a listed source for the claim. So how old is *prolly*?

Comment: The pronunciation is undoubtedly older than that spelling in print.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Writer Hugh Wiley seems to have been using it in dialogue in the 1920's. From his 1924 book *The Prowler* [(via Google Books)](http://books.google.com/books?id=cvQqAAAAMAAJ&dq=prolly+hugh+wiley&q=prolly#search_anchor):

> Dese folks is prolly dem bank boys whut buys all de fruit farms and makes dem yaller orange preserve.

He uses it in his 1922 book *Lily* [(via Google Books)](https://books.google.com/books?id=fP0nAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA248&dq=%22prolly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8-v_FxsLJAhVV5GMKHYowDGAQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22prolly%22&f=false) as well:

> "Looks like high tone folks. Visitin' prolly."
>
> "Prolly is. Us goes down dis alley an' in de back way, Demmy.""

The characters using *prolly* in these books are supposedly speaking in the African-American Vernacular. Depending on how good an ear Wiley had for dialect, this may indicate *prolly* first arose in Southern or African-American speech.

Comment: Nicely found. I just started using 'prolly' in txt and online chat about 10 years ago because I'm a bone-idle two-fingered keyboard pecker, but until now I've never even thought about actually *enunciating* it. I'm also an appalling lazy speaker though, and I normally only bother to articulate one of the two **b**'s (something like "praw-blee" is all you get from me unless I'm on my best linguistic behaviour! :-)

Comment: When I imagine that quote being read aloud, it seems to work just as well in the [Philadelphia dialect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3lZFiyd_-0)!

Answer (score 5):

The three oldest occurrences in the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) are from 1947, 1952 and 1954 (see below). This therefore supports what the article claims.
However, as @Peter Shor's answer shows, the word is actually even older (from 1922 at least).

> (...) up with the rest of the cows at milkin
> time and he knowed she was prolly out
> there on the gully some'eres with a
> fresh-born calf, waitin for it to (...)

Harpers Magazine (194712) pages: 498-505 (1947)

---

> (...) They say he wouldn't speak to Ma for a
> month after. He'd prolly have
> disinheritedme, seeing these, or shot
> Mott for a Texas traitor.(...) "

Giant,  Edna Ferber (1952)

---

> I'm quite aware that you come from a
> higher level of society. You prolly
> made a debut and all that.

Play BadSeed, Maxwell  Anderson (1954)

---

Note that [as Google NGrams shows](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=prolly&year_start=1940&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the word gained popularity in the Internet age:

[image]

Comment: Ironically, your own argument disproves you, because you can see in the Google search's first page a use of prolly in the correct sense from 1941. It's not much earlier qualitatively, but I didn't dig in the 19th century uses at all. It seems this needs further research. 
http://books.google.com/books?id=hfQYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22prolly%22&dq=%22prolly%22&hl=en&ei=PNvsTZLjCtGUswa18-jnCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ

Comment: @SurDin There's a note about that in my post. I'm not saying that the first occurrence was in 1947. My post was to show that the word already existed in the 1940's.

Comment: @Peter Shor just found in Google Books a book from the 1920's where the word was used. I updated my answer to point to his.

Answer (score 2):

[image: 1947 citation for prolly]

you might be looking [for this 1947 citation](http://books.google.com/books?ei=mersTd3zBIjcvwPfs43DDw&ct=result&id=VKRDAAAAIAAJ&dq=prolly)?