# Elision in the pronunciation of "probably"

Tags: pronunciation, adverbs, dialects

A student of mine has pointed out that in casual speech, my tendency is to pronounce the word "probably" as something like *prah-lee*.

I am a native speaker of American English without a specific regional dialect, as I moved frequently when young, both within the country and abroad.

I'm curious as to how widespread this pronunciation is, or if it's merely an indication that I'm a lazy speaker. Is this a regionalism I've unknowingly picked up? There is a Wiktionary entry for *[prolly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prolly)*, which indicates that I'm not alone in this pronunciation, but there's no indication of how common it is or where it's most prevalent.

**Note**: I'm familiar with the common tendency to skip the *ba* portion of the word, pronouncing it *prob-lee*; I'm specifically curious about the elision of both of the *b* sounds and the vowel between them.

**Edit**: I've been repeating the word over and over to myself since asking this question and realized that in particularly quick speech I seem to elide the L-sound, as well: *prah-ee.*

Comment: See also this question: [how old is the word "prolly"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/how-old-is-the-word-prolly)

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I missed that in my search (and just upvoted your answer).

Comment: Guilty! After trying this over and over just now, I think I could slip into "prah-lee" too, being a fast talker from the US Midwest, with that 2nd "b" being too much trouble to pronounce. :-)

Comment: Perhaps, *pro- **v** -ably* but never heard *prolly*. If it had even appeared in writing (per @Brian Hooper below), it's more likely there is/was such a word, possibly a synonym, not a mere variation in pronunciation but in spelling.

Comment: My impression is that it's quite common in fast, casual speech, even *prah-ee*; but it is hard for people to realise that they really say this.

Comment: @Cerberus I'd believe that; I hadn't noticed I was doing it until it was pointed out to me. And obviously if I'm speaking more formally/slowly, I pronounce the word differently.

Comment: @Kris, those of us leaving out the 2nd and 3rd "b" are not substituting a "v".  It's just being said as "pro'ly".  I can imagine it being used in a sentence like this, **"I needjour Chem notes, I can pro'ly get 'em back t'you by t'night."**

Comment: I say: _probably, proba'ly, prob'ly,_ and occasionally _pro'ly,_ depending on how carefully I'm talking. I often write _prolly,_ but it's more self-conscious than natural usage. I'm originally from Detroit.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I see a lauda-probs there. There ain't no one right way to talk in AmE all goes.

Comment: Is there a deep-south-AmE-dialect tag? Wiktionary calls it "Clipping (clipped pronunciation), colloquial, slang, notably Internet slang, Eye dialect spelling"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal American English pronunciation of the canonical /'prabəbli/ is a haplologized /'prabli/, with the /b/ often lost in rapid speech to /'pra:li/. That's the "prolly" that McBain and Higgins use. Just normal speech, better recorded, but it definitely flavours the dialogue.

There is also an emphatic form, stressed on the final syllable, /pra'bli/ or /pra:'li/, which can be used as a one-word response, or as an afterthought. I remember my brother saying it a lot when he was young, so this is nothing new, though it may be more common among younger speakers. I don't know.

Comment: /prɑli/'s my native pronunciation, and I'm old enough to know better. But I'm from the Deep South.

Answer (score 5):

I've come across *prolly* in the books of Ed McBain and George V. Higgins, set in (a thinly disguised) New York, and Massachussets, respectively.

As a South-Eastern British English speaker I sometimes (under the influence, sadly) shorten the word to *probly*.

Comment: Perhaps New York's the culprit, then. I was worried my stint in rural North Carolina was to blame.

Comment: @Cerberus  Cheer up, don't be sad. One man's dire degeneration of English pronunciation is another man's exciting evolution of language.

Comment: @Mynamite: That was rather an (ironic !) reference to Brian's "under the influence, sadly"...

Comment: @Cerberus Sorry, I missed that!

Comment: @Mynamite: Haha understandable.

Answer (score 2):

As a Brit, I don't recall ever coming across *prah-lee* -- and I don't think I would understand it unless it were obvious from the context. But, I would say that *prob-lee* is not uncommon.

Comment: Interesting. I think context must generally suffice, as I don't recall ever being asked to clarify myself. If you heard someone say *I'll prolly be there*, do you think you'd have a hard time understanding it?

Comment: @onomatomaniak - No, not in that sentence, but if it were spoken as a part sentence without a subject, say "prolly going do ..." I could possibly hear it as "Polly is going to do ...". (That's not a brilliant example because I find it difficult to think of one, but it could be ambiguous.)

Comment: @TrevorD I'm sure I say 'prolly' sometimes (I'm a Brit). I know I definitely say 'onny' for 'only'.

Answer (score 0):

I hear all versions from probably, prolly / prah-lee, prob'ly, to even Pr'y.  I grew up in Michigan nearer to Chicago, and I still live in Michigan.  I think this pronunciation variance is really telling of how informal upper Midwest/ Great Lakes people are feeling.  The shorter the word, the more relaxed or casual we are.