# What is the correct/popular pronunciation of Probably?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I heard people pronouncing "Probably" as "Praw-b-lee", is this limited to particular area or it is correct pronunciation every should follow.

Comment: Related: [Elision in the pronunciation of “probably”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113676/elision-in-the-pronunciation-of-probably) Both "b"s may even be lost, resulting in "prolly". Note: I don't think this word is pronounced "praw-blee" for speakers who use a different vowel in the words "thought" and "lot".

Comment: I can hardly think of any word with a pronunciation "that everyone should follow".

Comment: This is ***prolly*** Off Topic (POB). Which I can still write in a comment on ELU (where I've noted JLawler among others writing ***probly***), but on my smartphone it's just too much trouble to override the full spelling from predictive text.

Comment: @sumelic it may not be correct break up in syllables, but you got it right. Some times people ignore both "Bs".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fingers fumbling literally ... :). How come it is off topic?

Comment: I say "pra-bub-lee".

Comment: @paul: what I meant to say in my previous comment is, some people use different vowels for "awb" and "ob". It's not just a matter of syllabification; even if you put the "b" in the next syllable, they would have a contrast between "praw" and "prah" (in some US accents).

Comment: paul: Well, the mere fact that I can actually call to mind one specific ELU user who happens to write his "short form" different to me kinda suggersts that anything said/written here is just people expressing opinions about what *they* usually write (or usually expect to see others write). Whatever - I've cast my POB closevote now, so it's too late for me to change it. But if I were coming at this question cold, I'm sure I'd just have closevoted against the "duplicate" @Peter's identified above.

Comment: There's often a significant difference in stress and intonation between the pronunciations without /b/'s. People who say "prolly" /pra:'li/ stress the last syllable, not the first one. "Probly", on the other hand (which is my most frequent pronunciation, as noted), is stressed on the first syllable /'prabli/